# How create macro that finds some objects and returns them?

Tags: scala, scala-macros

I have following macro (it finds startup objects - project is split across several sbt modules and some of them might need initialization):

```
object FinderMacro {
  def inject[A <: {def self(): A}]: Seq[A] = macro injectImpl[A]

  def injectImpl[A : c.WeakTypeTag](c: Context): c.Expr[Seq[A]] = {
    import c.universe._

    val tpe = c.weakTypeOf[A].typeSymbol
    val classess = c.mirror.staticPackage("<empty>").typeSignature.declarations.collect {
      case symbol if symbol.typeSignature.baseClasses.contains(tpe) =>
        Apply(Select(TypeTree(symbol.typeSignature), newTermName("self")), Nil)
    }.toList
    c.Expr[Seq[A]](Apply(Select(reify(Seq).tree, newTermName("apply")), classess))
  }
}
```

But it's not working:

```
Unexpected tree in genLoad: XXX.type/class scala.reflect.internal.Trees$TypeTree ...
```

followed by tree of macro invoker.
What should I do to get rid of this error?

EDIT:

I solved this problem by changing boot objects to classes and instancing them with constructor:

```
Apply(Select(New(Ident(symbol)), nme.CONSTRUCTOR), Nil)
```